# Nginx doesn't start

Tags: nginx

```
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2020-03-10 16:35:07 UTC; 9min ago
  Process: 5027 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5023 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5021 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25158 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─5029 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
           ├─5030 nginx: worker process
           ├─5031 nginx: worker process
           ├─5032 nginx: worker process
           ├─5033 nginx: worker process
           ├─5034 nginx: worker process
           ├─5035 nginx: worker process
           ├─5036 nginx: worker process
           ├─5037 nginx: worker process
           ├─5038 nginx: worker process
           ├─5039 nginx: worker process
           ├─5040 nginx: worker process
           ├─5041 nginx: worker process
           ├─5042 nginx: worker process
           ├─5043 nginx: worker process
           ├─5044 nginx: worker process
           ├─5045 nginx: worker process
           ├─5046 nginx: worker process
           ├─5047 nginx: worker process
           ├─5048 nginx: worker process
           ├─5049 nginx: worker process
           ├─5050 nginx: worker process
           ├─5051 nginx: worker process
           ├─5052 nginx: worker process
           └─5053 nginx: worker process

Mar 10 16:33:37 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Mar 10 16:33:37 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal nginx[5023]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Mar 10 16:33:37 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal nginx[5023]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Mar 10 16:33:37 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: PID file /run/nginx.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Mar 10 16:35:07 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: nginx.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 10 16:35:07 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Mar 10 16:35:07 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Mar 10 16:35:07 ip-172-31-36-184.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

I have such error and I don't know how to solve this problem.
I did all configurations but it still doesn't run.

Comment: Check if the default port setup on NGinx is available and not already used, have look to port 80 and 443. `lsof -i :80` and `lsof -i :443`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the root cause of the issue

```
PID file /run/nginx.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
```

you may need to start the NGINX server with root privileges or update the service file to have the pid file in another location that is readable by Nginx

```
PIDFile=/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I have already fixed it. I changed the pid file location to /run/nginx.pid. thank you for answer